# Changing the selected option after an HTTP request. Angular

Tags: angularjs

Using angular I do understand that you can make an option selected by assigning the value to the model.

```
$scope.options = optionArray[0];
```

This is also possible after an ajax/http request.

```
$scope.onChange = function(id) {
    $http.get('/API/GetJSONFor?id=' + id)
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.optionArray = response.data;
            $scope.options = response.data[0].Value;
        });
}
```

However, if the value in response.data[0] is not in the optionArray pre reassignment. Angular will attach it's cruddy null option and set that to selected.
Is there any work around for this? This null option has been one of the most aggravating things in working with angular so far.

EDIT

```
<select class="form-control" name="Options" id="Options" ng-model="options" ng-change="onChange(options)">
    <option ng-repeat="option in optionsArray" value="{{option.Value}}">{{option.Text}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Well, you're setting `optionsArray` to the response, and your model to the first option, so shouldn't it always be there? Can you post your `select` HTML code as well?

Comment: Supposedly it should always be there, but it is checking against the values which are strings and not Ids. So if the value doesn't exist it isn't there. I will add the select HTML on OP.

Comment: What do you mean "strings not Ids"?

Comment: Yeah, what I thought. Dont use `ngRepeat` on your `option` element, instead use `ng-options` - in your case it would be : `ng-options="option.Value as option.Text for option in optionsArray"`

Comment: The value of the option isn't numeric. It is a string.

Comment: Gotcha - see my answer below, it should take care of everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ngOptions` and not `ngRepeat` over an `option` element:

```
<select 
    class="form-control" 
    name="Options" 
    id="Options" 
    ng-model="options" 
    ng-change="onChange(options)" 
    ng-options="option.Value as option.Text for option in optionsArray">
</select>
```

And since your model is set to the `.Value` property, when you want to assign, you need to assign the `.Value` property back to the model:

```
$scope.onChange = function(id) {
    $http.get('/API/GetJSONFor?id=' + id).then(function (response) {
        $scope.optionArray = response.data;
        $scope.options = response.data[0].Value;
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried both methods: ng-options and ng-repeat; same situation for both. If the string doesn't exist in the pre existing option array then the null option is added. I think it has to do with angular checking against the option values before the DOM is updated. Also in my actual code I have the .Value property. Ill update the OP.

Comment: It shouldn't work like that... if you could make a fiddle that'd be helpful.

Comment: The issue was my select element was wrapped in ng-if, so the values were being updated before the DOM. Thanks for your help!